# How to find an property/directive added inside html tag of aem?

Tags: angularjs, aem

I am working on an AEM+angularjs existing project coded by some other team. I am trying to understand their code. But, I am unable to find a property added to the html element.

```
<html data-sly-use.urlConfig="za..co.component"
      ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController as myPage"
      data-model-path="${resource.path}.angular.json"
      data-aemapibaseurl="${urlConfig.aemAPIBaseUrl}"
      data-scpapibaseurl="${urlConfig.scpAPIBaseUrl}" 
      data-ibrapibaseurl="${urlConfig.ibrAPIBaseUrl}">
```

Here, I am not able to find from where data-model-path, data-aemapibaseurl, data-scpapibaseurl, data-ibrapibaseurl are getting resolved.

Any suggestions to check how all it we could get resolved.
If needed anymore information please let me know.

Comment: Are you trying to find those things with chrome developer tool?

Comment: @happyZZR1400. No i have the code base. I am trying to find it inside the code.

Answer (score 1):

At last i found it.
They are creating a data attribute which is later accessed from the controller level using the angular $attr service.

For getting value of data-model-path attribute, they will use $attrs.modelPath inside the controller.

Hope this will help someone else!!!!